# Node JS Error canvas.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: javascript

im trying to make a plugin discord in js and add the package: discord-image-generation but i need to have canvas installed on my PC, when i try to run it it's give me the error:

C:\Users\USER\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node is not a valid Win32 application.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discordjs")
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});
const DIG = require("discord-image-generation");

 client.on("ready", () => 
 {

 });

 client.on("message", message =>
 {
    let cmd = message.content.split(" ")[0] 
    cmd = cmd.slice(PREFIX.length)
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)

    if (cmd === "deletetrash")
    {
       message.delete()
       const user = message.mentions.users.first()  
        
      if (!user) return window.BdApi.alert(" Eroge Notification ",`You need mention someone. ❌`);

      Delete();
        
      async function Delete() 
      {
         let image = await new DIG.Delete().getImage(user.avatarURL).then(image => 
         {
            message.channel.send({
            files: [{
                     attachment: image,
                     name: "Delete.png"
                  }]
               })
            })
         }
    }
 });

 client.login(get_token.authToken).catch(() => 
{
   return window.BdApi.alert(" Eroge Notification ",`Oops, look like your token not working...`);
})
```

i have tried every solutions nothing work, thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: having this same issue running jest against a next.js project

Answer (score 0):

It means, that canvas build version and nodejs version are not the same. i.e. x32 canvas build and x64 nodejs build. Just build canvas for your node version

Comment: Did you have any link for download the right version for build canvas ? i tried multiple node js version it's not working